# Get properties types of Class.Type in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, reflection, mirror

I want to retrieve all classes that conform specific protocol

`protocol Service: NSObject {}`

and then build a dictionary

`[ClassName: [String array of property types]]`.

I managed to retrieve all classes using Objective-C reflection:

```swift
private static func allClasses<R>() -> [R] {
    var count: UInt32 = 0
    let classListPtr = objc_copyClassList(&count)
    defer {
        free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(classListPtr))
    }
    let classListBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: classListPtr, count: Int(count))
    return classListBuffer.compactMap { $0 as? R }
}
```

But I have problems with retrieving property types of services. From what I see Swift API requires object to get that info

`Mirror(reflecting: obj).children`

and even tho my protocol requires `NSOject` I don't want to create an object just to retrieve properties. Is there any other way to achieve it? From what I saw there is obj-c method `class_copyPropertyList` but you can only retrieve names and attributes with that, and you still need the object to get property types.

Comment: For properties you will need Swift's Reflection if they are not marked with `@objc`

Comment: `method_getTypeEncoding` and you will need to think how to decode returned result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. According to [Swift.org](https://swiftdoc.org/v5.1/type/mirror/) `Mirror`'s definition is "A representation of the substructure and display style of an **instance** of any type."